# python: combine lists to dictionary with header

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to combine two lists in to one dictionary type.

```
Name = ['John','Mary','Serena','Felicia']
Data = ['26','179','25','164','29','149','29','167']
```

desirable output in Json format

```
{"people":[{'Name': 'John',
     'Age': '26',
     'Height': '179'},
{'Name': 'Mary',
     'Age': '25',
     'Height': '164'}
{'Name': 'Serena',
     'Age': '29',
     'Height': '149'}
{'Name': 'Felicia',
     'Age': '29',
     'Height': '167'} ]
}
```

I try to combine with `list1 = {k: 'Name' for k in Name}` but the dictionary
shown 'John' = 'Name' which is reverse of what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a couple of nested zips & slices do the trick to build dicts in a list comprehension, as value of the outer dict:

```
Name = ['John','Mary','Serena','Felicia']
Data = ['26','179','25','164','29','149','29','167']

result = {'people':[{'Name' : name, 'Age' : age, 'Height' : height} 
          for name,(age,height) in zip(Name,zip(Data[::2],Data[1::2]))]}


print(result)
```

prints:

```
{'people': [{'Name': 'John', 'Height': '179', 'Age': '26'}, {'Name': 'Mary', 'Height': '164', 'Age': '25'}, {'Name': 'Serena', 'Height': '149', 'Age': '29'}, {'Name': 'Felicia', 'Height': '167', 'Age': '29'}]}
```

if you don't want to create "hard" slices, use `itertools.islice`, also would be interesting to convert integer values as integer, which avoids the easy trap of lexicographical compare of integers as strings later on:

```
from itertools import islice
result = {'people':[{'Name' : name, 'Age' : int(age), 'Height' : int(height)}
          for name,age,height in zip(Name,islice(Data,None,None,2),islice(Data,1,None,2))]}
```

(and also thanks to comments, no need to nest `zip` statements)

result:

```
{'people': [{'Height': 179, 'Age': 26, 'Name': 'John'}, 
            {'Height': 164, 'Age': 25, 'Name': 'Mary'}, 
            {'Height': 149, 'Age': 29, 'Name': 'Serena'}, 
            {'Height': 167, 'Age': 29, 'Name': 'Felicia'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
Name = ['John','Mary','Serena','Felicia']
Data = ['26','179','25','164','29','149','29','167']

dct = {"people": [{'Name': i, 'Age': j, 'Height': k} for i, j, k in zip(Name, Data[::2], Data[1::2])]}
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'people': [{'Name': 'John', 'Age': '26', 'Height': '179'}, {'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': '25', 'Height': '164'}, {'Name': 'Serena', 'Age': '29', 'Height': '149'}, {'Name': 'Felicia', 'Age': '29', 'Height': '167'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting approach.

```
>>> Name = ['John','Mary','Serena','Felicia']
>>> Data = ['26','179','25','164','29','149','29','167']
>>> keys = ['Name', 'Age', 'Height']
>>> it = iter(Data)
>>> {'people':[dict(zip(keys,i)) for i in zip(Name, it, it)]}
```

Can't make it too much more compact than this.

**Ouput**

```
{'people': [{'Name': 'John', 'Age': '26', 'Height': '179'}, {'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': '25', 'Height': '164'}, {'Name': 'Serena', 'Age': '29', 'Height': '149'}, {'Name': 'Felicia', 'Age': '29', 'Height': '167'}]}
```